# CometD doesnt start Jetty server in Java Multithreading

Tags: java, multithreading, cometd

I`m using CometD-3.0.2 in Java multi-threading application following [this](http://docs.cometd.org/2/tutorials/#server_stock_price) tutorial. Everything works fine when I create a service channel. I have created an object of my Socket Connection class, that also starts 10 Java Threads, in the CometD initialise class

```
public class Initializer extends GenericServlet
{
    private MainConnect connect;

    @Override
    public void init() throws ServletException
    {
       connect = new MainConnect();

    // Retrieve the CometD service instantiated by AnnotationCometdServlet
       StockPriceService service =   (StockPriceService)getServletContext().getAttribute(StockPriceService.class.getName());

    // Register the service as a listener of the emitter
    connect.getListeners().add(service);

    System.out.println("Service Added!");


     //Initiate the Threads
     connect.InitiateConnection();
 }
```

My Socket class gets initiated and java threads are running as well. However, the jetty server never get started here.

My Service class

```
@Service
public class StockPriceService implements StockPriceEmitter.Listener
{
@Inject
private BayeuxServer bayeuxServer;
@Session
private LocalSession sender;

public void onUpdates(List<StockPriceEmitter.Update> updates)
{
    for (StockPriceEmitter.Update update : updates)
    {
        // Create the channel name using the stock symbol
        String channelName = "/stock/" + update.getSymbol().toLowerCase(Locale.ENGLISH);

        // Initialize the channel, making it persistent and lazy
        bayeuxServer.createIfAbsent(channelName, new ConfigurableServerChannel.Initializer()
        {
            public void configureChannel(ConfigurableServerChannel channel)
            {
                channel.setPersistent(true);
                channel.setLazy(true);
            }
        });

        // Convert the Update business object to a CometD-friendly format
        Map<String, Object> data = new HashMap<String, Object>(4);
        data.put("symbol", update.getSymbol());
        data.put("oldValue", update.getOldValue());
        data.put("newValue", update.getNewValue());

        // Publish to all subscribers
        ServerChannel channel = bayeuxServer.getChannel(channelName);
        channel.publish(sender, data, null);

        System.out.println("Service hit!!");
    }
}
}
```

Java multi-thread run method

```
  if (workerID == 0) {
                    try {
                        System.out.println("Running");

                        Random random = new Random();

                        List<Update> updates = new ArrayList<Update>();

                        // Randomly choose how many stocks to update
                        int howMany = random.nextInt(symbols.size()) + 1;
                        for (int i = 0; i < howMany; ++i)
                        {
                            // Randomly choose which one to update
                            int which = random.nextInt(symbols.size());
                            String symbol = symbols.get(1);
                            float oldValue = values.get(symbol);

                            // Randomly choose how much to update
                            boolean sign = random.nextBoolean();
                            float howMuch = random.nextFloat();
                            float newValue = oldValue + (sign ? howMuch : -howMuch);

                            // Store the new value
                            values.put(symbol, newValue);

                            updates.add(new Update(symbol, oldValue, newValue));
                         //   System.out.println("Updates from Emitter Class: " + updates);
                        }

                        // Notify the listeners
                        for (Listener listener : MainConnect.getListeners())
                        {
                            System.out.println("Listners value: " + listener);
                            listener.onUpdates(updates);
                        }

                        // Randomly choose how long for the next update
                        // We use a max delay of 1 second to simulate a high rate of updates
                        long howLong = random.nextInt(1000);
                        scheduler.schedule(this, howLong, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);




                        Thread.sleep(3000);


                    } catch (InterruptedException  e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
```

Overall scenario, Im implementing a Sever that uses Sockets to receive client A connection then receive data from clients. I need this data to stream to client B. Jetty server doesnt start when I initiate the Socket class/ open a socket connection.

Any information is much appreciated

Comment: You must clarify what you mean by "it doesnt start the Jetty server but my threads start running" and what you mean by "java multi-threading", since both makes no sense to me. Also the part about sockets and Jetty makes no sense. CometD is fully multi-threaded safe and if you strictly follow the tutorial instructions you will have your example running fine. Finally you did not specify what CometD version, what Jetty version, etc.

Comment: @sbordet sorry, Ill update my question again

Comment: @sbordet Could you check it now, Ive updated my question.

Comment: There is no information on what your `MainConnect` class does, which is the heart of your question.

Comment: I solved it by separating my multi-threading and cometD